# MongoDb - Update array of json objects

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, mongodb

I would like to update an object from a JSON objects array. Here is the schema

```
qualifications:[ {
    Experience: [{
      title: String,
      companyName: String,
      location: String,
      years: Number
    }],
    Education:[ {
      school: String,
      years: Number,
    }],
    Licences: [String],
    Honnors: [String],
  }],
```

For example how can I push an object to the `Education` array? This is what i have tried so far.

```
const updateEducation = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.body.userid },
      {
        $push: {
        
            qualifications:{
              Education: {
                school: req.body.educationSchool,
                years: req.body.educationYearText
              }
            }
          
        },
      },
      { new: true }
    );
```

And then i use this to remove an object

```
const deleteEducation = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.body.userid },
      {
        $pull: {
          "qualifications.Education": {
            school: req.body.school
          }
        },
      }
    );
```

But unfortunately in the update function i get **"error": "Plan executor error during findAndModify :: caused by :: The field 'qualifications' must be an array but is of type object in document**

what is wrong?

Comment: Please attach an example/image of qualification in your database

Answer (score 0):

The `qualifications` property of the `User` is an **array** of arrays, in other words, 2D array. And subarray receives data in an object. You are trying to access `Education` by object keys. But `Education` is in index 1 of `qualifications` array.

```
const updateEducation = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.userid });
    user.qualifications[1].push({
      school: req.body.educationSchool,
      years: req.body.educationYearText 
    });
    await user.save();
  } catch (err) {
    // handle error here...
  }
);
```